# Rails 4.1.8 "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

how am i going to pass through these. when installing the rails bundle, what i see this

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed
(https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

how am i gonna solve this problem help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I took the liberty of formatting your post a little bit. It is very helpful to make use of the available formattings. You'll get used to them pretty quickly. Putting four spaces in front of lines will let them look like your terminal.

Comment: It's important to understand that **"Rails 4.1.8 “DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle”** is a warning.
I would bet you are using windows. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually install a newer rubygems, the long version can be found here: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#installing-using-update-packages-new

Basically, download the latest rubygems here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases and do these steps:

```
gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem
update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

The "DL is deprecated" is not actually an issue. The SSL-Certificate / SSLv3 is your actual problem.